# Hook to StandardOutput of a running process

Tags: c#, .net, process, inter-process-communicat, redirectstandardoutput

I need to hook to an already running process' StandardOutput stream.
The process is not started by my app but I know it was started with `RedirectStandardError = true`.

So the big picture is: there are 2 processes that run concurently (name them P1 and P2). When a certain condition is met, P2 starts a new process P3. P2 does not need to consume P3's output (still it sets the `RedirectStandardError` to `true`), instead it informs process P1 that P3 exists. P2 does this by sending P3's PID (Process Identifier) to P1 process (through a pipe, let's say). P1 is now interested in P3's output. I can get the associated Process object of P3, but when I am trying to read the output with this method:

```
StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

it fails saying that "`StandardError has not been redirected.`"

P2 can read the output, of course... but P1 needs the data.

Comment: I suspect to simulate transferring ownership you'd need to go pretty deep.  May I ask -- if you can already pass P3.Id from P2 to P1, why not pass output from P3? That's the fallback you want to beat, right?

Comment: @SingleStepper yes, I would prefer to have direct access to P3's output if possible, I already have some code implemented for that...